# Incomplete road labels on tiles' edges rendered my python-mapnik

Tags: python, mapnik, osm2pgsql

We imported Europe data file to Postgres database with psm2pgsql and rendered tiles with generate_tiles_multiprocess.py which comes from python-mapnik tools and road labels look quite strange as per attached screenshot. Why do these labels look incomplete ? Have you seen anything like this before ? I can provide further details if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have right solution!

```
<Map buffer-size="512"
```

AND

```
<ShieldSymbolizer clip="false"
```

instead of

```
<ShieldSymbolizer avoid-edges="true"
```

(all occurences) in osm.xml worked.